# wny radio button group not work'n properly in the code

Tags: android, user-interface, coding-style

```
<RadioGroup>

                <TableRow>

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/a"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:text="lolo"
                        />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/b"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:text="sh"
                         />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow>

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/c"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:text="s"
                        />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/d"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:text="cannot be determined"
                         />
                </TableRow>
            </RadioGroup>
```

i want to select one rdio button out of four it is acing like 4 seperate radio button??? ,all r getting selected,i'm new in android develoment so kindly guide me thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RadioButton` views must be immediate children of the `RadioGroup`, for the `group-effect` to work.

So, if you add 'TableRow' under `RadioGroup`, the group nature that should be seen on `RadioButton` will not function.

For `RadioButton`'s grouping to work, try something like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/a"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="lolo" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/b"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="sh" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/c"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="s" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/d"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="cannot be determined" />
    </RadioGroup>

</RelativeLayout>
```

If you are so concerned about the row-column structure, then use your own layout XML file itself and implement `setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener)` on the radio buttons. When any of the radiobutton gets clicked, corresponding listener block will be called and then uncheck other radio buttons.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have used radio group and define radio button inside that group this is correct but refer this link [Radio Button Group](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-radio-buttons-example/) this might be useful

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TableRow>

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/a"
                        android:text="lolo"
                        android:button="@drawable/btn_touch"/>

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/b"
                        android:text="sh"
                         android:button="@drawable/btn_touch"/>
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow>

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/c"
                        android:text="s"
                        android:button="@drawable/btn_touch"/>

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/d"
                        android:text="cannot be determined"
                        android:button="@drawable/btn_touch"/>
                </TableRow>
            </RadioGroup>
```

where `btn_touch` in drawable folder is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- When selected, use grey -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/selected1"
          android:state_checked="true"/>
    <!-- When not selected, use white-->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/unselected1"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: create two images of checkbox one selected and another unselected on.which help you to come out of this.

Comment: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/selected1').

Comment: @dreams13 you have to put two images named selected1 and unselected1 in your drawable folder.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help you if you want to keep the buttons on split rows:
1. Remove the group from your xml since you don't need it :

```
<TableRow>
                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/a"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:text="lolo" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/b"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:text="sh" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow>
                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/c"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:text="s" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/d"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:text="cannot be determined" />
                </TableRow>
```

2. Use this in your activity to make it work:

```
private RadioButton a;
    private RadioButton b;
    private RadioButton c;
    private RadioButton d;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
        ButtonChange clRadio = new ButtonChange();
        a = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.a);
        b = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.b);
        c = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.c);
        d = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.d);
        a.setOnCheckedChangeListener(clRadio);
        b.setOnCheckedChangeListener(clRadio);
        c.setOnCheckedChangeListener(clRadio);
        d.setOnCheckedChangeListener(clRadio);
        ...
    }
    public class ButtonChange implements OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton radio, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked)
                switch(radio.getId()) {
                case R.id.a:
                case R.id.b:
                case R.id.c:
                case R.id.d:
                    a.setChecked(false);
                    b.setChecked(false);
                    c.setChecked(false);
                    d.setChecked(false);
                    radio.setChecked(true);
                    break;
                default :
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This should do the trick.